# Removed Contents replaced back after hitting back button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[image]

i have a two columns where i will move selected field from one column to another column after clicking on next button and if i come back all moved fields will be present.

**Image 1** shows how it is before clicking on next button.(working fine)

**Image 2** shows after clicking on next button and coming back to first page

> Column 1 HTMl

```
<div class="menu">
    <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox1' >
</select>
```

> Column 1 JS code

```
self.firmData.forEach(function (data) {             
 $("#lstBox1").append($('<option class="items">').text(data.DisplayName).attr('value', data.DisplayName));                        
  });
```

> 2nd column HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox2' >
</select>
```

> 2nd column JS code

```
self.data.forEach(function (data) { 
$("#lstBox2").append($('<option class="items">').text(data.columnsexpo).attr('value', data.columnsexpo));
 });
```

**NOTE**

`self.data` and `self.firmData` values are coming from api

Comment: How do you change the data on your backend?

Comment: i am not changing anything in backend all i need to do is using only frontend

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Could you pls describe what exactly you try to achieve?

Comment: see in first image i move field from 1st column to 2nd column using move right button everything is ok in this but if i go to next page and again come to previous page the fields which i had moved will also be there in 1st column

Comment: I guess your problem has nothing to do with the code you posted. I would really need to see the rest of it.

Comment: Please create a code snippet or give link to jsfiddle or something like that I mean show the working code

Comment: So what are you expecting after clicking back button? It is doing what it's supposed to do. Do you want to load new data from api? Are you saving the data on next button click?

Comment: @MunimMunna see first column values are coming from api so after hitting next and again if we go back api is getting refreshed and all the values which i had moved previously is getting back into first column i dont want the api to get refresh again

Comment: @MaheerAli these values are coming from api so if i create a fiddle it will not show my problem as i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `localStorage` to keep the selected items in the cache.

Here the complete fiddle link. https://codesandbox.io/s/ly1l9x7no9

Here the working demo from that fiddle. https://ly1l9x7no9.codesandbox.io/

Refresh the page, Once you moved the items between the left and right boxes to check the selected items are retained inside the same boxes.

Comment: what u had given it works perfectly for my question but even if i refresh the page also it is still showing the same if i refresh the page it should be like previous

Comment: You mean, you don't want to keep the selected items in localStorage? If yes, then simply comment the line no 82 in the fiddle.

Comment: if i do that and if i go to next page and come back again the fields which i had moved to 2 nd column  will also be erased. i dont want that to be removed only if i refersh the page the local storage should be cleared

Comment: No worries thank you i got the solution to clear local storage on page refresh

Comment: i need one more help i have a dropdown menu if i change dropdown value the 1st column value should be cleared how to do that

Comment: I can't get you. can you explain more?

Comment: see i have a dropdown field in this page if i change dropdown value the first column should be empty and it should replace with some other fields

Comment: when you change the dropdown the first column of the left box should replace with the selected value. I'm I, right?

Comment: not with selected value i have some other values which is also coming from api 1st column value should replace with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191200/discussion-between-prabu-samvel-and-chethu).

Comment: i had attached one more question in chat discussion if its possible can you solve that for me

Comment: if you are free can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377352/check-if-a-group-of-values-exist-in-array-javascript/56377437?noredirect=1#comment99355883_56377437

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the get response for your data is cashed? In this case the browser will not send a new request for the data when you hit the back button but still using the old. You can check this in the Network part of the development tools in your browser.

Depending on what kind of Backend you have you could deactivate cashing on that api call. You can also prevent caching Client site with `Cache-control: private` in your header.

Comment: i am getting new response on clicking back button

Comment: @chethu: so when you hit the next button are you making an api call to update first colum values in the backend?

Comment: @MuraliNepalli i am not making any api call after hitting next button actually after hitting back button api  is getting refreshed

Comment: @chethu: But when you hit back button, does this code run again?. 
 self.firmData.forEach(function (data) {....});

Comment: yes when i back button that code is executing again