# Check if a group of values exist in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have a table like this in which i have some values for location . If this location values contains any other values except `"California" "New york" ,"HQ" , "Florida"` it should show alert message like location is not valid .
I have tried following code .

```
   tabledata.DataTable.forEach(function (data) {
       var locate = data.Location;
     if (locate.includes(data.BranchName)) {
       alert("Success");
      } else {
     alert("failure");
             }                            
      })
```

**UPDATE**

```
branchDetails.forEach(function (data) {
       console.log(data.BranchName);
  });
```

here `data.BranchName` contains `"California" "New york" ,"HQ" , "Florida"` and `locate`  contains the table location value .

My issue here is even though the table contains `"HQ"` it is showing as failure

Comment: Is `data.BranchName` an array? It seems like the logic of `includes()` is reversed. The parameter should be the value to find, i.e. `arr.includes(valueToFind[, fromIndex])`. See [Array​.prototype​.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: is the `data.BranchName` string?

Comment: No `data.BranchName` is not a string i am taking that value from an object and sorting out using `forEach`

Comment: Shall i know which datatable lib are u using? If possible can update the datatable initialize code? @chethu

Comment: @Prabusamvel its ok i got the solution for that Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think you just used includes the wrong way. Try using:

```
data.Branchname.includes(locate)
```

**EDIT**

You could also safe check in case data.Branchname is undefined

```
data.Branchname && data.Branchname.includes(locate)
```

Comment: if i use like that i am getting error `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Comment: could you provide an example model of your data object?

Comment: I updated the question with a safe check for data.Branchname

Comment: data is nothing but array of objects in that i am sorting out only BranchName and `data.Branchname` is showing only last value (Florida)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the `includes()` as it is `array.includes(value)`

```js
tabledata.DataTable.forEach(function (data) {
       var locate = data.Location;
       var branch = data.BranchName;
       //if branch is string you need to do like this
       /*
        var branch = data.BranchName.split(',');
       */
     if (branch.includes(locate)) {
       alert("Success");
      } else {
     alert("failure");
             }                            
      })
```

Comment: no branch is not a string i have a object values from that i am sorting out branch check my updated question

Comment: If i use in your way i am getting error as `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`